# Unable to register startup script

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net

I am using the following code inside a `btn` `Click` event:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "exampleScript", "alert('you just registered the start up script');", true);
```

The script gets registered inside the `<body>` and I do not get any alert.

What's the way to register startup script and get this alert message?

Comment: Have you tried adding the parentheses to the function call? For example, instead of "exampleScript", try "exampleScript()".

Comment: thats the "script key", not the function name. It just registers the script to the registerstartupscript with that key

Comment: are you trying to register startup script from within update panel ?

Comment: @Devjosh Sry abt that. I was just doing a sample application without any ajax.

Comment: no problem @Ananth try the solutions suggested by us all hope you will get your answer out of them cheers!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using AJAX?

So whenever you have an instance of  ScriptManager on your page, you need to register the Script using ScriptManager. So you need to change the code like this

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "exampleScript", "alert('Hello');", true);
```

Comment: Thanks .Iam doing a sample application without any ajax. Your solution worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you need to call `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` during an event like `Page_Load()`, not Button_Click.

That way, to execute the code, you need to a client-side Javascript call to the code

```
Page_Load()
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "exampleScript", "yourFunc();", true);
}

<asp:Button OnClientClick = "yourFunc()" .....
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myKey", "alert('you just registered the start up script');", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to execute the script on button click then don't use`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`

i will advise you to use `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` instead it attaches the JavaScript with button client click event

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page),alert(' i am executed on button click'), true);
```

refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx)

Use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` if you want to execute script on every time the page loads

you can also optionally  use the following method
`btn.Attributes.Add("onclick","<script>alert('hello alert')</script>");`
in the Page_Load() event if you wish to register the script with button on the page load

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is already given so let me explain what options you have in ASP.NET.

ASP.NET provides two ways of including JavaScript resources to your pages.

1. ClientScriptManager (accessible via Page.ClientScript)
2. ScriptManager and ScriptManagerProxy

The second option supports more or less the same as the first but has also support for ASP.NET AJAX and WebService & Script References. If you don't use any of those extra's then usually I choose the first option.

It's not clear what exactly you're using but If you use a update panel then you will have to use the second option.